# on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Имеется ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Понимаю что ссылаюсь на нулевой объект, но не могу понять, как это исправить.
Перепробовал все что знал.

В `recyclerAdapter` пытаюсь по клику задать невидимому обьекту статус `VISIBLE`

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ItemViewHolder>
    implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    private List<File> mItems;
    Context mContext;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout

private final OnStartDragListener mDragStartListener;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<File> mImgGson, Context context, OnStartDragListener dragStartListener) {
    mDragStartListener = dragStartListener;
    mItems = mImgGson;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layoutFirst);
    return itemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mItems.get(position)).fit().centerCrop().error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.handleView);

    holder.handleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View trash = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.trash_can);
            trash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/layoutFirst"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trash_can"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="40dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ImageView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layoutFirst);
```

Метод `findViewById` ищет `layoutFirst` в `view` и естественно не находит, потому что `view` инфлейтится из `R.layout.item`, а `layoutFirst` находится в разметке активити.

Comment: Да, действительно, Вы правы! Но подскажите как бы Вы решили эту проблему. Я решил её тем что передал в адаптер view с той активити , в разметке которой был данный элемент, и при определении id использовал его. Но мне кажется это не лучший способ

Comment: @evb я бы передавал в адаптер лисенер, навешал его на item и в активити ловил бы события